# Get NonPagedPool (NPP) Base Address on any Windows OS

Tags: windows, memory, exploit, kernel-mode, memory-dump

Is there a way to get the the base(start) address of the NonPagedPool in Windows ?

I know that it's dynamic for Post windows 7 Operating Systems (Does this include Windows server 2008 ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution when reading these two articles:

1. https://pentest-tools.com/blog/bluekeep-exploit-metasploit/ (Extracting the NPP Address)
2. https://medium.com/@alexandrevvo/testing-bluekeep-cve-2019-0708-metasploit-module-on-windows-7-ef3f28217b7b (Finding the NPP)